# Draw a picture with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I would appreciate your help trying to draw with tikz the picture below. 
I admit that I'm not very good at Tikz and I'm looking forward to the help of tex.stackexchange.com to achieve this drawing.

Many thanks for your precious advice

[image]

Comment: This scheme is very easy. You can create it modifing the second tutorial on the [pgfmanual](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the document. I've been looking for a drawing that looks like him but it's not there.

Comment: You need to look for the elements you need instead, like nodes, draw, arrows etc. It's not that hard. Take your time.